# I have a list of numbers, and I want to take the difference between the current and previous value

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I have a small array and I want to take the difference between the current and previous value, but my array starts with 1. but I don't want 1 - 5 to occur. I want the data set to start and end at the original values:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])


diff = list()
one_year = 1
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    value = x[i] - x[i - one_year] #subtract current year with year before
    #print(x[i-one_year])
    print(value)
    diff.append(value)

print(diff)

-4
1
1
1
1
```

I want the data to start with 1, not -4.
How do I fix this for loop?

Answer (score 3):

You could use this :

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print(np.diff(x)) #==> 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

diff = [1]
one_year = 1
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    value = x[i] - x[i - one_year] #subtract current year with year before
    #print(x[i-one_year])
    print(value)
    diff.append(value)

print(diff)
```

Comment: Try now, I think u changed ur params in the question